# get site rss feed url in Joomla 1.5

Tags: api, rss, joomla1.5

I surfed the net high and low, but I cannot find anything about it!

I want to create a module with a link to the rss feed of the site.

How can I get the rss url of the site I install the module on? I cannot find anything about it !!!

In wordpress it can easily be found using get_bloginfo()

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try using the URL in this fashion:

```
http://siteURL/index.php?format=feed&type=rss
```

Comment: Thanks, but i was hoping for a general solution that could work for every website.For now I'm using JURI::base()."index.php?format=feed&type=rss", but i thought there was a function to get the rss url directly!

Comment: Yes, you are right, I don´t know any other way, have you tried asking this same question in Joomla forums?

Comment: looks like is not the only missing fast link in joomla. There's not even a function to reach your model folder fast!